# Remove AD User account with powershell fails

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, powershell

Am trying to delete a list of accounts that are either no longer needed or people who have left our employ.  I was thinking powershell would be the easiest and so far have the following script to remove all their group memberships and then remove their account.

```
$users = Get-Content U:\UsersToDelete.txt

foreach ($user in $users){
    $groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user | Select-Object -Expand Name
        foreach ($group in $groups){
            Remove-AdGroupMember -Identity $group -Member $user -Confirm:$false
            }
    Remove-ADUser -Identity $user -confirm:$false
    }
```

The group membership removal works fine and some of the accounts are deleted but not all.  The error I am receiving is:

```
Remove-ADUser : The directory service can perform the requested operation only on a leaf object
```

I am guessing it may be something to do with their having a mailbox in Exchange but am otherwise at a loss.  Is there anyway to force the removal of the account from powershell or is their a variant of the command I could use?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track with the mailboxes. Some users likely have other objects underneath them so you can't delete the users until you delete those objects. This link has a useful code snippet you can adapt for your use:

http://andrewbeaton.net/faq/2012/07/04/cannot-remove-ad-user-with-nested-leaf-objects/

Comment: This is most likely the answer.  You will get a similar error using `Remove-ADComputer` for computer objects which have child BitLocker nodes.

Comment: In AD, many objects can be containers as well as objects in their own right.  As a container, it can, er, contain other objects.  The AD cmdlets expect containers to be empty before they can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Remove-ADObject` when dealing with Active Directory objects containing other objects.  Adding the `-Recursive` parameter allows for nested objects to be removed.  This works for Active Directory User objects as well as others.

Reference:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/remove-adobject?view=windowsserver2019-ps